# C# COM interop, wrong signature generated?

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop

Like many I ran into problems with passing of C# arrays to COM clients in C++. My guess is that this is due to having wrong signature generated by CLR COM Interop. Serious claim, yes, but here's the deal.

C# COM server consumes type library called GenTechLib.tlb.

C++ COM client expects a notification from COM server by a callback function with a signature like below. It is quite obvious what this does. C++ client is expected to get number of elements, and that many addresses, values and timestamps. But what happens is that C++ client only gets correct first value, the rest is garbage and due to not passing arrays correctly from C#.

```
HRESULT Notify(unsigned long dwCount, BSTR * psAddresses, VARIANT pvarValues,    DATE * pdtTimestamps )
{
  // let's say that received dwCount is 2, so therefore, below should work

  // this gets proper value
  BSTR addr0 = psAddresses[0];

  // this however gets pure garbage
  // result is the same for values and timestamps
  BSTR addr1 = psAddresses[1];
}
```

On C# side, signature of above function, when generated from a referenced TLB file is this:

```
void Notify(uint dwCount, ref string psAddresses, ref object pvarValues, ref DateTime pdtTimestamps);
```

So a code like this, although it compiles and runs fine does not produce desired results.

```
// all of below are arrays of 2, properly new'ed and filled
string[] arrAddresses;

string[] arrValues;
object obValues = arrValues; // function signature requires 'object'

DateTime[] arrDates;

notificationListener.Notify(2, ref arrAddresses[0], ref obValues, ref arrDates[0]);
```

Unfortunately, I cannot modify signature of Notify(). It is generated from TLB file. This is output from decompiling with ILSpy of compiler generated Interop.GenTech.dll file.

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("F97D74BE-AC1C-404E-B463-142916096A24")]
[InterfaceType(1)]
public interface INotificationListener
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    void Notify([In] uint dwCount, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string psAddresses, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object pvarValues, [In] ref DateTime pdtTimestamps);
}
```

Notice the difference between C++ and C# signatures. What can we tell C# COM interop to generate signatures to pass back arrays ( ref string[] instead of ref string)? Can this signature be overridden in such a manner to accept arrays? Or was it a problem of generating TLB from dll in the first place?

COM interface dll from which TLB (GenTechLib.tlb) is generated is a dll created in ancient VS2003 in C++. Unfortunately, I don't have source of it.

What can be done from C# language point of view? If the output parameter type is:

```
ref string strArray
```

Can it be filled with strings sequential in memory, and through COM interop fool the C++ COM client so that it received array of strings in form of BSTR*?
Perhaps use unsafe blocks? But even with that, I have some doubts.

If it were up to me, whole code base would be in C++, but it is what it is.

Any thoughts? Hints?
Thanks.

**Update:**

I stopped using reference to .tlb type library, but instead manually corrected signatures of some functions, most notably Notify()

Check out this monstrosity of function signature below (no ref keyword anymore), works ok in C++ COM client code where all elements of array are now received. My C++ COM client code is only a simulation of what I think a real system is like, but I'm 99% sure that safe arrays are not used.

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("F97D74BE-AC1C-404E-B463-142916096A24")]
[InterfaceType(1)]
public interface INotificationListener
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    void Notify([In] uint dwCount, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.BStr, SizeParamIndex = 0)] string[] psAddresses, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeParamIndex = 0)] object[] pvarValues, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.R8, SizeParamIndex = 0)] double[] pdtTimestamps);
}
```

I also needed to manually correct a signature of another function too, but this was the main blocker. It would seem that referencing a type library in your C# project doesn't always mean that you will get correct function signatures. Perhaps Visual Studio type library code generator can only get you so far.

Comment: Generated interop is based on TLB, which is based on IDL. C++ header or declaration is not enough to specify how an interface will work (especially with out-of-process marshaling) Please show us the original IDL declaration, as some parameters may not be correctly declared in there, for example, the 3 last parameters are typical candidates to problems.

Comment: The C++ component is authored clumsily and in general is only usable from a C++ program.  It should have declared these two arguments as SafeArrays to make them compatible enough.  The only thing you can do about it is decompile the interop library and modify the argument types.  You'll probably need [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0)].  DateTime is not correct either, should be double[].

Comment: @Simon, no original IDL available of this GenTechLib.tlb I'm afraid. When I import this TLB with C++ tlh/tli header files get generated, that's where I got C++ signature from. I realize that last 3 parameters are troublesome, but that's how things were done back in the 90s and I must conform to it.

Comment: @Hans, actual C++ client component on real system which will consume my COM dll is very old. Doubt very much that authors used SafeArrays. Decompiling looks acceptable. Will simply lose reference to TLB and use decompiled code instead. Guids are good so should work. Will look into DateTime...it seems to marshall correctly to COM's DATE, which as you correctly point out is in fact a double floating point type. Looked good to me in debugger, but will definitely take a closer look.

Comment: If you don't have original code or cannot recompile, you can declare the interface manually in C# and stop using the TLB

Comment: Thanks guys. I finally got things running properly. It's in the update section of the original question.